# chinese words in request (jsp - servlet)

Tags: java, encoding, cjk

I m having a html form with input field, so when is used english for the input there is no problem but using chinese words i got some incorrect string in the servlet, what encoding i m suppose to use and how to set it?

in the html form

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>  
...
 <form method="post" action="<%= action %>"  accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

in the servlet

```
 String charset = request.getCharacterEncoding();
// here charset is always null
 String shareContent = request.getParameter("content");
```

For example
input : 朋友你好
in servlet come : "æåä½ å¥½"

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

can you try if this works for you:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8 ");
```

also you may want to add a filter to do the encoding on all request/response.